# Android Activity Show View

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity A to start another Activity B.In activity B, there are some functions that download resource form internet. When A jumps to B, I want to show B'view immediately.Actually,B'view will be hidden until all functions ready.
I want to B show "searching.... " when it handle the data.

```
A:
    Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    intent.putExtra("result",obj.getText());
    A.this.startActivity(intent);


B:
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.success);
        TextView text = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        text.setText("searching....");         
        Bundle bun= getIntent().getExtras();
        String tempIsbn=bun.getString("result");

        //some functions
        bookinfo=getResultByIsbn(tempIsbn);
                  .....
    }
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11999651/1263679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple thread can do the trick in the oncreate function of your activity B:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            bookinfo=getResultByIsbn(tempIsbn);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Update UI

                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `bookinfo=getResultByIsbn(tempIsbn);` to another thread. Use Java threads or AsyncTask to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can an `AsyncTask` to hide and display your result

```
private class PerformTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        /**
                      * display view to show progress
                      **/
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        bookinfo=getResultByIsbn(tempIsbn);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        /**
                      * hide progress
                      * display results
                      **/
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```